# Is it possible to return only a certain fields when inserting a new document?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-mongodb-native

I nedd to get the new document back with _id field only. Something like this:

```
db.users.insert({name: 'Jonh', age: 27}, {_id: true} , function (err, user) {
   if (err) {}

   // need to be user with only _id field.
});
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED**

The second parameter to the `insert` callback is always an array of the inserted objects, and you can't prevent the other fields from being included.  However, you can use [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create the result you're looking for:

```
db.users.insert({name: 'Jonh', age: 27}, {_id: true} , function (err, users) {
    if (err) {}

    users = users.map(function(user) {
        return {_id: user._id};
    });

    // users now contains objects with just the _id field   
});
```

Comment: What if I will use batch inserting? Should I use loop?

Comment: @Erik See update answer as you can use `Array#map` for a cleaner solution.